# EC2 can't SSH into github

Tags: git, ssh, github, amazon-ec2

Cloning into website...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Constantly getting this on my EC2 instance, even though I have generated an SSH key and added the SSH key to the allowed keys on Github.

When I test authentication I get this:

Enter passphrase for key '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Hi DaveHewy! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

But when I try and clone a repo, no such luck.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of handling several keys and keeping ssh github keys laying around on your EC2 instance you should consider using Agent Forwarding instead. That changed the way I deploy.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

With Agent Forwarding you are essentially using your local keys while logged into the EC2 instance. If someone else logs into the instance they won't be able to pull/push the repo if they have no access to it.

It's easy, clean and secure.

The only good reason you have to have SSH keys on a remote host is to have continuous integration or automating deployments. In that case you should use a deploy key.

Comment: Totally forgot I could do this, cheers! Used it before as well. I now have solved both angles anyway :)

Comment: "Using the deploy key you can only pull."? The GitHub [docs](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) say "Deploy keys always provide full read/write access to a repository."

Answer (score 8):

Switched to root user with

```
sudo su
```

And re-set up my SSH keys using the following page provided by Github - https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Worked fine after that.

Comment: Appreciate this. Was using the "ubuntu" user and needed to use the root user.

Comment: So, out of curiosity, why can the ubuntu user not clone but the root user can?